# Hotkeys/Keyboard Shortcuts Not Working

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

At random times, all of the hotkeys on my computer just go away. I try to minimize all windows by pressing <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>... nothing happens. Even hotkeys in other programs go away. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> does nothing in any program I use that saves. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> doesn't open the downloads window in Firefox. Sometimes it just randomly comes back. Logging off/on doesn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried switching the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really old, and I fixed it by just using another keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same behavior sometimes. This is mostly fixed by pressing all the alt-, ctrl-, shift- and windows-keys once.  I think one of those become "stuck" sometimes (windows thinks they are pressed, but they aren't). And they are *released* when pressing (and releasing) them once.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. I tend to smack the keyboard out of annoyance rather than just pressing them. Works well for me =)

Answer (score 0):

You should get a hot-key creator or re-install your driver software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't wish to appear obtuse and I'm sure you have already checked, but the last time something similar happened to me, it was a paperclip under the <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys of my keyboard...
A simple keyboard swap out may also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me sometimes, not just in vista, also happened to me in XP

When that happens, i just click a couple times on the "stuck" key and it starts working fine again

It seems that it is caused by the application thinking that the key is pushed in